# WSO2 configuring production deployment with a domain name

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We are releasing WSO2 API Manager and Identity server to production.
The environment is AWS EC2. 
Currently we have bought a custom domain name via AWS Route 53.
How can i configure WSO to work with these URLS? Also we have to install CA signed certificates with this domain name in WSO2. How to achieve it?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

when you move to production , you need to remove default key store comes with wso2 products and user you new key and CA singed cert. you can find the guideline for that in this blog[1]

To configure the domain , change the hostname and MgtHostname in carbon.xml[2]

[1] http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2015/05/update-key-stores-in-wso2-api-manager.html

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Configuring+carbon.xml

Comment: How can i map WSO2 to start in custom domain?
I have a custom domain and ssl is bought for this domain..so i have to make wso2 to work with this domain..then only ssl will work

Comment: Go to wso2am-2.0.0/repository/conf/carbon.xml and change the following tags.

<HostName>DOMAIN_NAME</HostName>

<MgtHostName>DOMAIN_NAME</MgtHostName>